# An algorithm for finding all the cycles and an algorithm for finding the shortest cycle in the attached pictures (two examples)

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

In a directed, weighted multigraph:

- There could be multiple edges between every two nodes. The two examples are given below.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

1- Which algorithm can find *all the cycles*, *passing through all the nodes at least once*, in the attached pictures?

2- Which algorithm can find *the shortest cycle* (the least total edge weight), *passing through all the nodes at least once*, in the attached pictures?

Concerning the first example, the cost of the shortest cycle is 13, concerning the second example, the cost of the shortest cycle is 6.
As far as I know, the TSP finds the shortest cycle, which includes at least 3 nodes, but in my case, a cycle can also have two nodes.

Note:

- A cycle must include *all the nodes* and the nodes should be visited *at least once*.
- A cycle can include *only two nodes* such as 0->1->0 (Example 2)

Comment: An algorithm that finds all cycles will also find the shortest - you just need find the shortest in the output.

Comment: Your pictures indicate you want this for directed multigraphs

Comment: @ravenspoint: Yes. You are right, but I am wondering if we can use a variant of TSP that specifically finds the shortest cycle (even cycles with two nodes)?

Comment: TSP is slow and complicated.  Use the combination of DFS/Dijkstra which is fast and simple to implement.

Comment: Your pictures show edge weights.  Do you want the shortest ( fewest edges ) path or do you want the path with the least total edge weight?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: @ravenspoint: I clarified it now. I meant the least total edge weight.

Comment: Do you need a cycle that goes through all the vertices in the graph or any cycle in that graph? If the latter ravenspoint answer does the trick for you.

Comment: @ravenspoint: I should highlight that all the cycles must pass through all the nodes. Sorry for the ambiguity. I clarified this.

Comment: @ciamej: a cycle that goes through all the vertices in the graph. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the definition of a cycle.  "In graph theory, a cycle in a graph is a non-empty trail in which only the first and last vertices are equal. A directed cycle in a directed graph is a non-empty directed trail in which only the first and last vertices are equal."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)#Circuit_and_cycle  Whatever it is you are looking for, it does not seem to be a cycle.  In particular, any graph that contains one or more leaves ( i.e. a vertex of degree 1 ) cannot contain a cycle that visits every node once.

Answer (score 2):

You only need one algorithm. An algorithm that finds all cycles will also find the shortest - you just need find the shortest in the output.

If the graph does not have multiple edges between vertices then the algorithm is a modified depth first search. When a previously visited vertex is reached, the Dijsktra algorithm is applied to find the path that forms the shortest cycle that leads back to the back edge to the previously visited vertex.  You can find more details about this and C++ code that implements it at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Cycles

You will have to modify this to handle multiple edges between vertices.

- remove all multiple edges ( so each vertex pair has at most one edge between them, going in the same direction )
- Apply the cycle finding algorithm
- Loop over the vertex pairs that have multiple links between them.  If a pair is in a cycle, add extra cycles corresponding to using the alternate edges.

Comment: Based on your answer, we can obtain the shortest cycle polynomially, which contradicts the TSP's complexity which is an NP-complete problem.

Comment: TSP is the wrong algorithm for this problem.

Comment: May I ask you why TSP does not work to find the shortest cycle?

Comment: I should highlight that all the cycles must pass through all the nodes. Sorry for the ambiguity. I clarified this.

Answer (score 1):

Start by removing edges so that the graph is **not a multi-graph**. In example 1, that means removing the weight 5 edge. That edge cannot be part of the solution, because the shortest path will always use the weight 3 edge instead.

Then add edges so that the graph is a **complete graph**. You can do that with the Floyd-Warshall algorithm (FWA). The output from FWA is the adjacency matrix for the complete graph. Note that if there is no path between a pair of vertices, FWA will assign an infinite weight to the edge. Typically, you use a large number to represent infinity, e.g. 1000 would work for the examples.

Once you have the adjacency matrix for the complete graph, you can apply the **standard TSP algorithm**. If the solution contains an edge with an "infinite" weight, then there is no solution.

If the solution contains a edge that doesn't exist in the original graph, then you need to [reconstruct that path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Path_reconstruction). In example 1, the TSP solution might be `0->1->2->0`, so you would need to reconstruct the path from 2 to 0.

Note: the choice between using this method or the DFS method suggested by ravenspoint depends on how many edges the original graph has. If the average [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)) in the graph is low, then DFS might be faster. Either way, the first step is to remove edges so that the graph is not a multi-graph.

Comment: May I ask if you have considered that the cycle must pass through all the nodes (at least once)?

Comment: I am wondering how it is possible to apply the DFS algorithm as its complexity is polynomial, which is way lower than the standard TSP, which is an NP-complete!

Comment: As far as I know, the standard TSP works on graphs with at least three nodes, but example 2 is a multigraph with two nodes!

Comment: @AlexanderJafari The answer to the first comment is yes, because TSP will visit every node.

Comment: About the second comment: I've thought about it a little more, and I think you are correct that DFS won't work, because there's no way to force the DFS to make progress. Normally DFS has a `visited` array that makes sure that each node is only visited once, but here nodes can be visited multiple times. The array could be changed so that edges are only used once, but I think it's possible to make a graph where some edges need to be visited multiple times. That would make DFS unworkable.

Comment: The third comment: I don't know any limitation in TSP that wouldn't work with 2 nodes. But if that's the case for the solver you have, then a graph with 2 nodes can be solved as a special case.

Comment: Could you please also elaborate on my first question, i.e., 1- Which algorithm can find all the cycles, passing through all the nodes at least once, in the attached pictures?

Comment: @AlexanderJafari I'm beginning to think that I don't understand your question. Are you trying to find all of the cycles or visit all of the nodes. In the first example there are three cycles: the 4,4 cycle, the 2,3 cycle, and the 2,5 cycle. Finding and traversing all of the cycles is a much different problem than TSP. In fact, if the goal is to trace every cycle then I would say the solution to example 1 is 2,3,2,4,4,3,2,5 where the numbers are the edges.

Comment: In the above, I have asked two questions, from which you have answered the second one (the shortest cycle). Now, my first question asks to find all possible cycles passing through all the nodes at least once. In example 1, one cycle could be 2,4,4,3, or 2,4,4,5

Comment: @AlexanderJafari Ok, that clarifies things. You are asking two questions, and I did answer the second one. I missed the first question because example 1 doesn't show the answer to the first question. I think it's best to post a separate question here on stack overflow that focuses on the first question, and provides the expected answer for the first question.